# XPath for selecting multiple HTML `a` elements

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I'm pretty new to XPath and couldn't figure it out looking at other solutions.

What I'm trying to do is select all the `a` elements inside a given `td` (`td[2]` in example) and running a for statement to output the text contained within the `a` elements.

Source code:

```
multiple = HTML.ElementFromURL(url).xpath('//table[contains(@class, "mg-b20")]/tr[3]/td[2]/*[self::a]')

for item in multiple:
    Log("text = %s" %item.text)
```

Any pointer in how I can make this work?

Thanks!

Comment: What library/framework are you using? I could not figure out it from your source code alone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The XPath you need is pretty close:

```
//table[contains(@class, "mg-b20")]/tr[3]/td[2]//a
```

I don't know what library you're using, but I suspect it is the [Plex Parsekit API](http://dev.plexapp.com/docs/api/parsekit.html). If so, parsekit uses [`lxml.etree`](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html) as its underlying library, so you can simplify your code even further:

```
element = HTML.ElementFromURL(url)
alltext = element.xpath('string(//table[contains(@class, "mg-b20")]/tr[3]/td[2]//a)')

for item in alltext:
    Log("text = %s" % item);
```

This will even take care of corner cases like mixed content, e.g. this:

```
<a href="#">I am anchor text <span>But I am too and am not in Element.text</span> and I am in Element.tail</a>
```

Comment: Thanks! Finally got this working. Yes I'm working on creating Agents for Plex. Its so hard finding documentation for beginners like me. Greatly appreciate it.